# Using Angular Library in Non-Angular App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2-directives

I have building a library with Angular 2.x/4.x to use in another projetcs.
The problem is that : Some app's are legacy, not build in Angular, like ASP NET MVC. 
I have tried using the bundle '.js' of my Angular module, generated in by the build of project, but I get error's of Angular depedencies . 
That's possible ?

If, yes. How can i do that ?

Comment: Have you found something?

Comment: I need to do the same, so far what I have to do is to create an angular app, import my library and then build everything into a single bundle, that I will import and it works, but with some difficulties.