# Integrate an Angular library into a non-angular app

Tags: angular, aws-lambda, angular-library

My scenario is as follows:

- I have built an Angular library that exposes a service, whose dependencies are passed in the constructor
- I have a separate AWS Lambda function (triggers on cron) that would need to use this service.

My question is: is there a way to bundle the library so that the service can be easily instantiated in the non-angular app, and avoid having to construct the dependency graph manually?

Ideally, from the lambda function I would just call something like

```
const service = MyAngularService.instance();
service.doStuff();
```

Is it at all possible?

Similar to: [Using Angular Library in Non-Angular App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849587/using-angular-library-in-non-angular-app)

Comment: For now the service I'm exposing has a limited dependency graph, so I have decided to expose a factory method that creates the service and instantiate + injects all the dependencies manually.